# Shortcut to create a Java Object in Vscode

Tags: java, object, visual-studio-code, shortcut, vscode-snippets

Is there a keyboard shortcut to create an object in Java in VScode or how to write a User Snippet for that.

i.e. shortcut for "Object_TYPE ref_VAR = new Constructor();"

Answer (score 0):

You can [Install snippets from the Marketplace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_install-snippets-from-the-marketplace)

Or

[Create your own snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets)